# Refer to a variable with a string

Tags: java

Let's say I have 2 variables:

```
char p1;
char p2;
```

Then I have a method that does something with one of the variables, based on the `int` argument:

```
    void someMethod(int number) {
        if (number == 1) {
            p1 = 'a';
        } else {
            p2 = 'b';
        }

    }
```

This is not very scalable.

Could I refer to the `p1/p2` by some string appending, like `"p" + number`?
Or any other way not to have to write a separate `if` for each case?

Comment: Use an array or list or some other sort of Collection data type.

Comment: What would you need to do with `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: @takendarkk you mean to put the `p1`, `p2` into a collection and refer to them by the index?

Comment: Is p1 always going to be 'a' and p2 always going to be 'b'? You might consider setting up an enum if that's the case. But as others have mentioned, it depends on the broader context of what this is being used for.

Comment: The `p1 = 'a'` is just an example. Basically, I want to do this in multiple method and generally, I need to somehow manipulate the variables or read them.

Comment: Ok, but what is your actual use case. Why do you need to manipulate variables this way? Maybe there is another, simpler and cleaner way but since we don't know what exactly you are trying to do it is hard to actually suggest anything else.

Comment: +1 to @JoãoDias
To me it feels more a modelling issue, than something that can be fix with a feature like that.
Try explaining the complete issue

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
char[] p = new char[2];

void someMethod(int number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        p[0] = 'a';
    } else {
        p[1] = 'b';
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the actual question, the approach is much better. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Reflection (a java API to manage classes and instances).

Try this (provided the method and p1 are all in the same class and you want the value in the same instance)

```java
this.getClass().getDeclaredField("p1").setChar(this, 'a');
```

Another different point is what is the problem you are trying to solve using reflection. I can tell you that Reflection API is rarely used and it should not be the solution for every day problems. Probably your approach is not the best. Try to open another question explaning the business problem, not the solution you think is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the variables, then you can use an array + mapping logic instead of a multitude of variables and conditions.
Let's say you have one array and one mapper:

```
char[] p = new char[2]; // or "as many as you need"
static Map<Integer, Character> mapper = new HashMap<>();

static {
    mapper.put(1, 'a');
    mapper.put(2, 'b');
    // ... "as many as you need"
}

// number needs to be between 1 and "as many as you need" (inclusive)
void someMethod(int number) {
    p[number - 1] = mapper.get(number);
}
```

But if your mapping is linear 1->a, 2->b, 26->z then you don't even need a mapper as you can compute the corresponding character on-the-fly.

```
static char[] p = new char[26];

static {
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        p[i] (char) (i + (int) 'a'); 
    }
}
```

This being said, you're probably going down a bad road with what you're trying to achieve.

1. Your example does not look like Java
2. Your example doesn't achieve much, logically speaking

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the following:

```
if (number > 0 && number < 27)
     p = Character.toString(96+number);
```

97 is the ASCII code for Capital A (A)
You can use a similar method for lower case (a).